# how to find all elements of an List<string> which are not in two column of datable C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've a List(string type) "A" and a Datatable "B". I want to find out all the values of "A" which are neither in column1 nor in column2 of "B".

For demonstration:

List "A":

```
Lucknow
Delhi
Bhopal
Madhya Pradesh
```

Datatable "B":

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Uttar Pradesh | Agra | ID001 |
| Uttar Pradesh | Lucknow | ID002 |
| Madhya Pradesh | Bhopal | ID003 |

Result:

```
Delhi
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I find something like var C = A.Except(B.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a[0])); but this works only for 1 column.

Comment: How many elements are stored in the list and inside the table approximately?

Comment: Max 10 in both.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF core:

If you are looking for all the values of a list that are not saved in a table row's Column1 and Column2

```
       var listOfTownNames = new List<string>();
        // populate listOfTownNames with the town names data

       var listOfValuesNotInColumn1OrColumn2 = new List<string>();

        foreach (var townName in listOfTownNames)
        {
            var availableTown = _dbContext.Towns
            .FirstOrDefault(x.Column1==townName || x.Column2==townName);

            if (availableTown == null)
            {
                listOfValuesNotInColumn1OrColumn2.Add(townName);
            }
        }

        foreach (var value in listOfValuesNotInColumn1OrColumn2)
        {
            // print value
        }
```

If what you are looking for is the towns that are not in the list of town names:

```
            var listOfTownNames = new List<string>();
            // populate listOfTownNames with the town names data

            // get all towns which Column1 and Column2 data are not contained in the listOfTownNames list.
            var towns = _dbContext.Towns
                .Where(x => !(listOfTownNames.Contains(x.Column1) || listOfTownNames.Contains(x.Column2)))
                .ToList();

            // get access to each town's column1 and column2 value
            foreach (var town in towns)
            {
                // print town.Column1 value and town.Column2 value
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated inside the comments section both `ListA` and `DataTableB` are fairly small, no larger than 10.

This means you can do the filtering inside the memory, you don't have to transfer `ListA` to the database.

```
var dataTableB = dbContext.B.ToList();
var listA = new List<string> { "Lucknow", ... };
```

Calculating those values that are not present in columnA

```
var columnAValues = dataTableB.Select(b => b.ColumnA);
var notPresentInColumnA = listA.Except(columnAValues);
```

Calculating those values that are not present in columnB either

```
var columnBValues = dataTableB.Select(b => b.ColumnB);
var notPresentInEitherColumns = notPresentInColumnA.Except(columnBValues);
```

Here is a [working dotnetfiddle version](https://dotnetfiddle.net/au11g6).